# Xcode attribute on property does not match the property inherited from 'UIViewController'

Tags: ios, objective-c

Updating an old project for Xcode 7, and I'm getting an error I didn't get before the update.

.h file:

```
@interface TableRowViewController : UITableViewController {
    UIImage *rowImage;
    NSString *nibName;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *rowImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *nibName; // <-- error here
@end
```

throws error:

> 'copy' attribute on property 'nibName' does not match the property inherited from 'UIViewController'

.m file:

```
#import "TableRowViewController.h"

@implementation TableRowViewController

@synthesize rowImage;
@synthesize nibName;

@end
```

Comment: Just as a heads up, remove the instance variables and synthesized names. Back in the day, you had to manually do this, now instance variables are generated along with synthesizing properties.

Comment: @TheCodingArt Just to make sure I understand... Am I getting rid of the \@synthesize and \@property lines, the NSString line too?

Comment: Just the @sythesize and the instance variables in the brackets

Comment: @TheCodingArt When I remove those lines I get: `Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'nibName' because it is 'readwrite' but it will be synthesized 'readonly' via another property`

Comment: @TheCodingArt Ok, I switched the property name like Phillip Mills suggested, and commented out the instance variable and synthesize lines and it appears to be working! I probably won't update all of the other places that are like that, as they are working (unless there's a good reason?), but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's telling you that a superclass already has a property with that name: `@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *nibName` and that the attributes are a mismatch for your redefinition of it. (copy/readonly vs. strong)

If your purpose in having this property is the same as the superclass, you can get rid of your definition.  If you have a different purpose, you should rename it so there's no conflict.

Comment: It must be a superclass that I don't have access to, since when I comment out that property line I get a bunch of errors saying that I'm trying to write to a readonly property. Doing code search only returns this one result. I switched it to rowNibName instead... had to fix it a couple dozen other places, but it appears to be working!

Comment: It's in `UIViewController` and, yes, it's marked readonly there (the declaration I pasted into the answer).